# HTTP GET test servers

Tags: sockets, http

I'm writing a program that downloads files. It's basically working but chunked encoding and downloading data that is sent without a "Content-Length" header field are currently untested. That's why I'm looking for a server that allows me to test whether the following parts of my program are working:

1) Chunked transfer mode

2) HTTP servers that do not set the "Content-Length" header field before sending the data

Does anybody know HTTP servers that I could use to check whether I've implemented chunked transfer mode and downloading data without "Content-Length" correctly?

Comment: If you are familiar with Python, you can refer to this gist. https://gist.github.com/josiahcarlson/3250376

Comment: I've already written the necessary code. I'm just looking for a server that uses chunked transfer mode so that I can check whether my code is working...

Comment: Yes, the gist itself contains the server part, you can use it to start up a server which support chunk encoding for testing purpose.

Comment: Oh, alright, sorry. That might be a solution in case nobody else comes up with a server that uses chunked mode...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough www.bing.com uses chunked encoding to deliver the home page. If you can read it, you are doing something right.

Comment: I can confirm this, using Chrome and the Element Inspector tool, on the Network tab.